# Sudden Loss of Reputation

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, users

A minute ago I reached 1,512 in 5 minutes from 1,474. Now i am back to 1,474 in just 5 minutes. How is this possible . Please any moderator tell  me where I lost my rep. What is happening.

**Ed:**

I lost my Rep again this time I was 1534, now I am 1519 - but meta shows I have 1529.

[image]

But in meta it shows

[image]

Comment: What does http://superuser.com/reputation say you have?

Comment: Right now i have 1,474

Comment: I swear I had 1,512

Comment: You may of done - often you will find the rep report *doesn't* match your visit rep on the site (mine is out by ~20 at the moment) - because deleted questions and the like do not get discounted from your rep immediately. It *could* be that your account has had it's rep recalculated to correct these errors, but maybe not, I don't think they happen often. Maybe a moderator can confirm if this has happened on your account..?

Comment: I lost my reputation again this time i was 1,534, now i am 1,519

Comment: Now I lost like 40 reps today for no-reason. This is going sad

Comment: Btw - ignore the rep score on meta, it is *not* live - I often find after a rep change on SU that meta.SU does not match. As for changes - remember that it is also possible someone removed an up vote or un-accepted one of your answers, these will (I believe) instantly change your rep score.

Comment: Rep isn't the be-all and end-all of StackExchange. it is a major motivating factor, yes. Also, you expect people to vote for you and rep you - but you aren't participating in the voting process. At all. Rep going up and down is a natural process, learn to live with it.

Comment: @Sathya that doesn't mean I could loose something which I earned for no particular reason. For me answering the correct answer and getting reps is like a game , so i hate it when i loose it. It keeps me motivated in answering more questions.

Comment: @subanki If it's like a game - you can't win all the time. And you aren't losing them for no particular reason. Re-evaluate yourself. Your answers seem pseudo-spam. Google + copy & paste with little attribution. Do we do it ? Yes. Do we do it all the time? No. There are substantial number of answers where the answer posted is nowhere related to the question asked. All of these will factor in when somebody sees an answer. People come to the StackExchange for a more personal approach feedback - not bits of text sourced from various places.

Comment: As a sidenote, the spelling & grammar nazi in me says, loose != lose.

Comment: @Sathya you could be right and yeah about spelling mistake, sorry i am sitting in the dark and typing. About google thing i thought they where great better answer which i myself cant explain it better. If I am right you asked me to take releent content from the links than posting as links , so as a time saver i just copy pasted. oh by the way can please tell where is that site where we one can chat. I cant find it anywhere

Comment: @Sathya and moderators  should I vote to close this question as this might not come handy to others and the question looks terrible with so many images

Answer (score 6):

I deleted one of your posts because of it violating copyright. As there was quite a few deleted posts on your account I also did a reputation recalculation to ensure that your rep shows correctly for the rep leagues and the current competition. During a reputation recalculation and votes received for any of the following is removed:

- Deleted Posts
- CW Posts

Comment: oh that could be the reason , I deleted a up-voted answer as it was not the exact answer. Thank you. Also can please specify me what is the daily max rep cap. Is it 195 or 250 ?? What happens after I reach that rep cap. And oh yeah Thanks for keeping everything updated and clean :D (it must be tough)

Comment: By the way can you tell which post you deleted and what content did I violate

Comment: @subanki. Firstly. Please stop deleting questions. This is not your personal playground. If I see any more posts unnecessarily deleted I will suspend your account. Secondly, in one of your answers you copied and pasted the complete content from a website that clearly stated that their content is copyright. Read the sites before you just copy the content, lastly. The rep cap is 200. After the cap, you don't gain rep. Simple.

Comment: @subanki - Please note. Stop copying and pasting text from websites who have clearly stated copyright on their content. **This is your final warning. Should I find further posts with regards to this I will suspend your account**

Comment: How do I know its copyrighted material ??, any place in stack-ecxchange to chat ????

Comment: Also Where is the head office of stack exchange ?

Comment: @subanki. The head office is in the US. As for the copyright, simply clicking on the link to the resources you give, and reading their copyright notices, show that it is copyrighted material. No rocket science involved. **This is not a debate. I would expect your old enough and smart enough to figure out what is right or wrong.** We have already emailed you with regards to improving your interaction with the site. Rather slow down a bit and improve the **quality** of your posts rather then the **quantity**. The first is much more important to SU users.

Comment: @Diago - thanks for bringing this up/taking care of it.

Comment: @Diago, Sorry I didn't check my mails

Comment: @JNK Troggy has been on top of this, and the other moderators all were aware. I just happened to be online while it was getting out of hand.

Comment: Well then thanks to the whole moderating team!

Answer (score 0):

If you received a lot of reputation in 5 minutes, most likely the system thought someone was cheating or raising your reputation and corrected it.

If it wasn't automatic, it was probably just a recalc which happens when a mod wants it or periodically.

Comment: I did get those reps very fast indeed, sad they are now gone