# Different Reputation showed. Which one is correct?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

I´ve got a strange thing going on here. My reputation showed in the bar on top of the site is 714.

[image: reputaion1]

I was happy with it until i looked at `http://superuser.com/reputation` yesterday.
The reputation score there is 717.

[image: reputation2]

Which score is the correct one and how is this possible? I assumed something like an automatic recalculation, but it has been this way foor two days now and I guess it issn´t a recalc at all. So, can anybody tell me if what´s going on here? I don´t care about the three points but I really would appreciate the knowledge how something like this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a reputation recalculation on your account and this should now show correctly. For future reference, the reputation report is always the most correct.

Please see my answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1420/sudden-lost-of-reputation/1423#1423) for why this would happen. It is rare however for reputation to be higher then the report, but it has happened at times, where question where deleted and then undeleted for example.